# css matrix3d, arrastar o elemento mantendo a distorção

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Tenho andado a brincar com css Matrix3D neste código: http://jsfiddle.net/88Lv8kfp

Agora eu queria um ponto no meio para arrastar o elemento mantendo a distorção, mas não sei como fazer.

Até agora, a única coisa que eu consegui foi adicionar um ponto no meio com jQuery, mas não sei como atualizar sua posição.

```
$ ('<div>'). addClass ("pontos centrais")
  .appendTo ('body'). posição ({
    meu: "center",
    em: "center",
    de: elemento
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88Lv8kfp/1/

Comment: Não tenho tempo de continuar a olhar o código agora mas acho a pergunta interessante. Mudando o elemento que vai receber os pontos de `body` para `element` consegues arrastar tudo junto assim: http://jsfiddle.net/vkwru7dm/ O problema que não tive tempo de resolver é reorganizar a matemática para a transformação depois da mudança de referência. Dou nova olhada quando puder.

Comment: Você escreveu esse código ou pegou de algum lugar? Se pegou, de onde? Um pouco de documentação do código ajudaria.

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio, ta no bom caminho mas os pontos não deviam distorcer.

Comment: @bfavaretto tem alguma info aqui http://franklinta.com/2014/09/08/computing-css-matrix3d-transforms/

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Comment: não, ainda nao resolvi da maneira que queria. Provisoriamente resolvi o problema com algo semelhante ao que o @Sergio sugeriu.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o jQuery UI com a função `.draggable()`.

Usando `$('.box').draggable();` você consegue mover a caixa e manter a distorção. Só teria que fazer com que os círculos acompanhasse o movimento junto com a caixa.

Comment: sim, arranjei uma solução do género mas é uma solução  temporária porque o ponto central fica no centro da div ".box" e não no centro do elemento onde aplico a distorção